# How would I use stringstream to split up string of words and add them to a set of strings?

Tags: c++, string, set

```
//Before : source -> { source src set getname update getchar tgetstr }
           sink -> { sink mysql_query system require chmod broadcast }
//After : source src set getname update getchar tgetstr sink mysql_query system require chmod broadcast
```

```
    string line1;
    string line2;
    fstream SrcSnk;
    SrcSnk.open (filename);
    
    if (SrcSnk.is_open())
  {
    getline (SrcSnk,line1); 
    getline (SrcSnk,line2);
    string r = line1.substr(12, 46);
    string s = line2.substr(10, 47);
    std::cout << r;
    std::cout << s;
    SrcSnk.close();
  }
    stringstream r; 
    stringstream s;
```

I have used fstream and substring to read lines from a file and return a line of words.

I want to use stringstream to break these words up and insert them individually into a set of strings.

Comment: `istringstream iss(line); string word; while (iss >> word) myset.insert(word);`

Comment: See above, but ask yourself 1) How to I set up a stringstream with a string? 2) How do I read a word from a stream? 3) How do i add a string to a set? 4) How do I do the above in a loop? You should have either known the answers these questions, or been able to look them up for yourself. The trick to be a good programmer is not knowing loads of stuff, it's about being able to find out stuff when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iterator interface with relative simplicity:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::istringstream stream{"Word1 Word2 Word1 Word3"};

    std::set<std::string> set{std::istream_iterator<std::string>{stream}, {}};

    for (auto const word : set) {
        std::cout << word << '\n';
    }
}
```